# How to write the First Law of Thermodynamics for a non-stationary closed system?

Tags: thermodynamics

I know the First Law of Thermodynamics (FLTD) is written as
$dE = Q - W$

Where E is the total energy (Internal Energy (U) + Kinetic Energy(KE)+ Potential Energy (PE)), Q is the heat flow into the system and W is the work done by the system

It is can be written for a closed stationary system as,
$dU = Q - PdV$,

where $dE$ becomes $dU$ as for a stationary system there won't be any change in KE and PE and $W = PdV$ is the boundary work done to on the system by pressure.

How to write the work done by pressure for a Non-stationary system (assuming no change in PE).

That is

$dE= Q - W$

$dU + dKE = Q - $($PdV$,boundary work - Work done ON the system to accelerate it)

How to write the work done to accelerate the closed system in terms of system properties?

(I know this can be seen from a Open system perspective, but why is there no discussion to explain it from Lagrangian point of view?)